# what is ~ called and what does it meanin file paths

Tags: asp.net

why does visual studio do ~/Default.aspx instead of /Default.aspx?
i.e.

```
<asp:LinkButton href="~/Default.aspx">

vs
<asp:LinkButton href="/Default.aspx">
```

Comment: On unix systems, `~` is a shortcut for "home directory of current user". e.g. `~/foo` would be `/home/marc/foo`. In a webserver context, `example.com/~foo/index.html` is a shortcut for "index.html file in user foo's public_html directory"

Comment: On Unix.. systems.. ? His question is about Visual Studio. What does Unix have to do with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` character is called a "tilde" and in ASP.NET it refers to the application root directory or virtual directory.

A `/` will always refer to application root, whether you are in a virtual directory or not.

Comment: Worth mentioning - don't use tilde's in client-side URLs. Only use them in web/html-controls and in server-side code i.e. Redirection.

Answer (score 0):

The squiggly line is called a tilde, and, as the comment says, it stands for home directory